# Rails: Where does "inverse_friendships" come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a friends system on my site and just finished a railscast (#163) on self-referential associations (http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). At one point in the video, he creates a new relationship with the `inverse_friendships` table, but I never see him generate a `inverse_friendships` model or migration. Does the `inverse_` have to do with rails magic or is there something I missed?

models/user.rb

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Also, where does he get the `friends` column from? When he generated the scaffold for `friendship`, he created two columns `user_id:integer friend_id:integer` but didn't have anything on an actual friends table.

generating scaffold

`script/generate nifty_scaffold friendship user_id:integer friend_id:integer create destroy
rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such table. The `:class_name => "Friendship"` indicates that it is using the `Friendship` model, which uses the `friendships` table.

Comment: Oh.... is this just to make it so that the reverse relationship (person who is friended can access the person friending) is accessible as well?

Comment: Yes. This is what "self-referential" means. The model is associated with itself.